# layout_margin instead of separate ones doesn't works with negative value

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to use negative value for margin in my project. I found that it match for my purposes (with 0dp value margin still too much). But general tag "layout_margin" doesnt works for some reason.

This is main.xml with raw example that illustrate issue :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/main"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout

        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
           android:layout_margin="@dimen/default_button_margin"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="0dp"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:text="New Button"
           android:id="@+id/button1"/>
        <Button
          android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/default_button_margin"
          android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/default_button_margin"
          android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/default_button_margin"
          android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_button_margin"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="0dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:text="New Button"
          android:id="@+id/button2"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/default_button_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/default_button_margin"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/default_button_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_button_margin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button3"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/default_button_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/default_button_margin"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/default_button_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_button_margin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="New Button"
           android:id="@+id/button4"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java without import statements:**

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private final int FIELD_SIZE = 3;
    //private LinearLayout mainLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    private Collection<LinearLayout> layouts = new LinkedList<>();
    private final Button[][] buttons = new Button[FIELD_SIZE][FIELD_SIZE];


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
    }
```

**And dimens.xml :**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <dimen name="default_button_margin">-3dp</dimen>
    </resources>
```

Unfortunatly i dont have possibility to post image because of reputation.

Comment: You can link your image here and let someone add it to your post. Anyway, I doubt you can use negative margin in Android.

Comment: What are you actually want to do?

Comment: What do you want to achieve in your scenario ? But yes we can give negative margins in android.

Comment: I want make apps with square fields making with many square buttons like in tic-tac-toe and sudoku etc. And in this case i want achieve minimal spacing between buttons. Cant link image, because my reputation too low yet.